# Effective Implementation of RSA Public Key Generation and Encryption in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I am currently trying to write a program that will utilize a public key cryptosystem such as RSA or ElGamal.  I have been looking at different sources, and the closest I have gotten was in the [Bouncy Castle FIPS documentation](https://bouncycastle.org/fips/BCUserGuide.pdf) of public key encryption, where the sample code for RSA is somewhat simple:

```
public byte[] pkcs1Encrypt(RSAPublicKey pubKey, byte[] data) {    
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(“RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding”, “BCFIPS”);
   c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
   return c.doFinal(data);
}
```

I've worked often with symmetric key cryptosystems such as AES and Triple-DES (DESede), but I looked under the Bouncy Castle documentation, and found out that the `RSAPublicKey` is not a sub-interface/class of the `SecretKey` class.

Is there any way to generate this `RSAPublicKey` object, or is there a more efficient way to implement this kind of encryption with Bouncy Castle or the JCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bouncycastle document is not clear. `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);` requires an instance of [java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.55/src-html/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/RSAPublicKey.html) and not [org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.55/src-html/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/RSAPublicKey.html)

You can build `RSAPublicKey` using modulus and exponent, from the DER encoded data, or you can generate a new key pair

```
//RSA public key from DER encoded data
byte publicKeyData[] = ...;
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyData);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec );

//RSA from modulus and exponent
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);

//Generate a key pair using a secure random algorithm
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
keyGen.initialize(2048, random);
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
byte publicKeyData[] = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The only question I have from this is would you use a `SecureRandom` object to generate the `publickeydata` byte array?

Comment: `publicKeyData[]` is just an existent public key encoded as binary DER `publicKey.getEncoded()`. I have included a sample code to generate a new key pair using a `SecureRandom`. Oracle recommend to use a _strong random algorithm when creating high-value and long-lived secrets like RSA public and private keys_ Since JDK8 there are some implementations available. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html